# Web service method using update datebase in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-ajax

how to use update query in web service wethod

Answer (score 2):

Your web service method would call an update query just like any other method.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update field1 from Table where rowId = 7", conn);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```